# Android memory usage different devices

Tags: android, memory

There are a lot of tutorials,articles on the web about memory perfomance, and how to improve it,remove leaks etc..

But I haven't found information how many memory apps should use. Of course less is better,but I haven't found information about what is maximal memory which app can use and works well on the most of devices.

Is ok for app to use around 50-60 MB of RAM?

Comment: An ordinary Android SDK app can't *get* 50-60MB of heap space on many, if not most, Android devices.

Comment: How many can get?
I'm making some app with photo gallery and I need around 50mb memory

Comment: Some devices will give you as little as 16MB of heap space. It varies by device and is tied to system RAM, Android OS version, and screen resolution.

Comment: How to implement gallery with 16MB of memory?

Comment: Read "a lot of tutorials,articles on the web about memory perfomance, and how to improve it,remove leaks etc.", then follow the advice there.